# Problem generating APN SSL certificate after submitting to apple store

Tags: iphone, push, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm having trouble getting Apple to generate an APN SSL certificate for my app ID. I've submitted the application to the Apple store, and it is pending review.

I tested the application using an Ad Hoc app ID "${bundle_id}.adHoc" and everything went fine. I submitted to the Apple store with app ID "${bundle_id}.release".

Now I want to generate my production APN SSL certificate for use with my release application ID - but the developer portal doesn't want to. When I upload my certificate request, it sits for about a minute before telling me:

"We are not able to generate your Profile at this time.
Please try again later or try using the Provisioning Portal"

Is it impossible to generate your certificate while the application is under review or something? Should I have generated it prior to submission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was indeed that I was trying to enable for push while the app was in review. Once the app was approved, I was able to get my push certificate.  However, apparently you MUST enable for push BEFORE you generate your distribution provisioning profile, otherwise your app will not actually be able to register with the APN server when it is downloaded from the store.