# Apple push notification is working only for development and not for production

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am stuck with apple push notification services (APNS) only in the production mode... I am using the same php code on my virtual server for both production and development, so I believe the problem is not there ... 
Also I went through a lot of resources trying their suggestions but nothing worked for me:

1) [Push notifications work for Ad Hoc, but not when downloaded from the Apple store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614988/push-notifications-work-for-ad-hoc-but-not-when-downloaded-from-the-apple-store)

2) [apple push notification not working in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595720/apple-push-notification-not-working-in-production)
... and many others

So, I tried "Observing Push Status Messages" (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG24) in the document and I tried to log out the results of my APNS pushing!!

I follow this method (on my iMacPro) in terminal:

```
1-$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.apsd APSWriteLogs -bool TRUE
2-$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.apsd APSLogLevel -int 7
3-$ sudo killall apsd
```

and the output was very strange to me, and I have no idea what's wrong?

```
Failed to send activation record to service com.apple.ManagedClient.enroll
Added service com.apple.ManagedClient.enroll to activation record listener list
<APSPreferences: 0x7f8520f005c0>: Preferences may have changed, checking for any relevant changes
```

Sorry for being long, but I tried to explain the whole problem ...

Comment: you have 2 kinds of certificate, one for dev other for production to use on the device, are you using different ones?, http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 check the part [dev SSL cert n production SSL cert]

Comment: I am really aware of this, I have "apns-dev.pem" and "apns-prod.pem", and I followed the same exact tutorial ... So, I am sure that I am using pans-prod.pem, but it is not delivered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it!!!!!!!!!!!!
This is crazy from Apple side I guess. Anyway, after trying every thing here and there, the problem solved simply by:
"Deleting the table of deviceTokens I stored and upload the new tokens!!!!"

Not sure what was the problem, but now everything is working fine.